# laravel 5.1 восстановление Postgresql`s backup в транзакции

Tags: sql, postgresql, laravel

пытаюсь через `DB::statement(Storage::get('tmp/test.backup'));` восстановить дамп **postgresql**, но мне возвращает такую ошибку:

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 316: 1 1 2 1 {"1":"\\u041f\\u0435\\u0440\\u043c\\u044c","2":"\\u0...
          ^ (SQL: --
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--
```

строки в дампе:

```
COPY blocks (id, "order", tab_id, type_id, content) FROM stdin;
1   1   2   1   {"1":"\\u041f\\u0435\\u0440\\u043c\\u044c","2":"\\u041e\\u043f\\u0438\\u0441\\u0430\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435 \\u043f\\u0435\\u0440\\u043c\\u0438","3":2015,"4":"tratatatata.png"}
\.
```

дамп выполнял командой:

```
$process = new Process('pg_dump business_card_base --schema test > '.storage_path('app/tmp/').'test.backup');
```

laravel 5.1, Postgresql 9.3.9

в чём может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в том, что дамп не является обычным sql, дамп нужно грузить через `psql -f tmp/test.backup`. К сожалению, в laravel не ориентируюсь, но судя по всему будет что-то типа:

```
$process = new Process('psql -f '.storage_path('app/tmp/').'test.backup');
```

Comment: Примерно так и делал. Но так как это происходит внутри транзакции - не выйдет, по тому, что схема, которую я восстанавливаю из дампа - ещё существует =)

Comment: Не совсем понятно, вы хотите только восстановление в транзакцию обернуть, тогда [--single-transaction](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE). Или хотите в своей транзакции что-то сделать, восстановить базу, что-то сделать, откатиться - тут, по-моему врядли возможно, надо искать альтернативные варианты бэкапа, вплоть до своего велосипеда...

Comment: Второй вариант =)

Comment: Какой вы таинственный :) Ну проблема есть, надо искать подходы. Я бы начал с генерации DDL со --schema-only, если заработает как обычный statement, можно набросать скриптик выгрузки данных в ansi виде... ну как-то так. Очень необычный у вас usecase, придется изворачиваться...